# pass html form data to json php string

Tags: php, json, api, post

I've been able to perform a parse to post data to my api using this format:

Working sample:

```
    <?php

$appId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$private_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$geo_post = "/api/v1/geofence/";

$name = "Home";
$latitude = 38.646322;
$longitude = -121.185837;
$radius = 50;


$data = array(
  "name" => $name,
  "location" => 
  array( "latitude" => $latitude, "longitude" => $longitude),
  "matchRange" => $radius
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($appId.":".$private_token) // <---
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admin.plotprojects.com' . $geo_post );                                                                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      

$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

//print_r($content);

?>
```

Sample with Error message:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['add_new'])){

$appId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$private_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$geo_post = "/api/v1/geofence/";

$name = $_GET['db_geofencename'];
$latitude = $_GET['db_latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['db_longitude'];
$radius = $_GET['db_radius'];


$data = array(
  "name" => $name,
  "location" => 
  array( "latitude" => $latitude, "longitude" => $longitude),
  "matchRange" => $radius
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
'Content-Type:application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($appId.":".$private_token) // <---
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://admin.plotprojects.com' . $geo_post );                                                                            
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      

$content = trim(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

print_r($content);

?>
```

As you can see I'm using a string in my $data array, so i'm trying to capture the information from the form and pass it to the $data array, but if I use $_GET or $_POST i end up with an error message:

{ "success": false, "errorMessage": "The request content was malformed:\nExpected String as JsString, but got null", "errorCode": "BadRequest" }

what is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please post output of print_r($data_string = json_encode($data));

Comment: don't understand what you mean? if talking about what the out come is,  you can see the working one here: http://www.mygeofy.com/api/add_geo.php

Comment: hi just like to know what values are passed and what string value json_encode function passing to $data_string.
So change the line  :
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
 by
print_r($data_string = json_encode($data));die;
and paste the out put as comment here.

Comment: error message cleary states that problem is in request content so like to see what content pushed to service.

Comment: The data that I'm trying to pass are coming from a form field:

Comment: correct i like to check that data.

Comment: I'm unable to post the whole form:

Comment: I've explained as best as possible, in my discription, I'm just left out the form, as you should be able to tell where it's being called from: with  the $_GET['db_geofencename'] and so forth.

Comment: ok no problem,  so best i can think of is convert(type cast) your $latitude and $longitude into floating numbers. Don't depend on php auto type casting as some times internally it will keep it as string and i guess that api want $latitude and $lon... as floating numbers not strings.

Comment: ok, stupid question how would i do that. this sound new to me :-)

Comment: $value = floatval($stringvalue);

or

$value = (float) $stringvalue;

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you, that worked, I been working with php only for about a yr, but I really need to take a crash course to learn it more effectively. Thank you

Comment: Nice to hear that :) . i am posting it as answer please mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So best i can think of is convert(type cast) your $latitude and $longitude into floating numbers. Don't depend on php auto type casting as some times internally it will keep it as string and i guess that api want $latitude and $lon... as floating numbers not strings.